# How do I check the order of values in a group of values with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have groups where I have the group name in the first column and the characteristcs in the second. If the order in the second is wrong, the third column should be set to NOT OK. 
How do I check if the order in each group is correct?
[image]

Comment: Will this always be the order or the correct order? 'No Characteristic', 'Primary', 'Secondary', 'Tertiary'

Comment: yes 'No Characteristic', 'Primary', 'Secondary', 'Tertiary'

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = dict(num=['37671','37671','37671','37671','37671','37671','37671','37671','45559','45559','45559','45559','45559','45559','45559'],
         char=['No Characteristic','Primary','Secondary','Secondary','Secondary','Tertiary','Tertiary','Tertiary','No Characteristic','Secondary','Tertiary','Secondary','Secondary','Secondary','Tertiary'])
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df

ordered_list = [pd.np.nan, 'No Characteristic','Primary','Secondary','Tertiary']

def check_in_list(row, ordered_list):
    status = 'NOT OK'
    char_idx = ordered_list.index(row['char'])
    char_prev_idx = ordered_list.index(row['char_prev'])
    if char_idx >= char_prev_idx:
        status = 'OK'
    return status

dfs = []
for num in df['num'].unique():
    df_ = df.loc[df['num'] == num, :]
    df_['char_prev'] = df_['char'].shift(1)
    df_['check'] = df_.apply(lambda row: check_in_list(row, ordered_list), axis=1)
    dfs.append(df_)
dfs = pd.concat(dfs)

dfs
```